# How to include all files within a folder to functions.php?

Tags: functions

My functions.php includes other function files located within a 'functions' directory.

Currently they're individually added, in the format of this example:

```
include('functions/login.php');
```

How can I modify this to include all files within the 'functions' directory, without listing them individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include/require all *.php files recursively using following function.

```
foreach(glob(get_template_directory() . "/*.php") as $file){
    require $file;
}
```

Alternatively You can use following function as-well.

```
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(get_template_directory().'functions/');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach($Regex as $yourfiles) {
    include $yourfiles->getPathname();
}
```

P.S Got the solution [From Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php#97228).

Comment: @ JItendra Rana ... Thanks. can this be modified to include files from sub-directories inside the 'functions' directory?

Comment: Do you want to include all the files recursively in all sub-directories ?

Comment: Updated the answer to more elegant solution for recursive directories. Please check

Comment: @ JItendra Rana ... Thanks. I'm getting various errors with the updated code, so will instead use your previous suggestion, which I think was: foreach(glob('/add_path_to_theme/wp-content/themes/theme-name/functions/*.php') as $file) {include $file;} If that is your code, it might be worth re-adding it to your update so others can access it.

Comment: Updated the answer. Pls Check

Comment: Is there any security issues with doing this?

Comment: Well its a broad answer. 
It depends on what kind of app / framework you are dealing with. 
And weather files can be accessible directly or not. 
Stay away from such kind of thing if you are not sure what your are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it from my functions.php file in WordPress:

```
/**
 * Functions
 * Require all PHP files in the /functions/ directory
 */
foreach (glob(get_template_directory() . "/functions/*.php") as $function) {
    $function= basename($function);
    require get_template_directory() . '/functions/' . $function;
}
```